# aspectj-maven-compiler plugin : how to weave JRE System.*?

Tags: maven, aspectj, java

I'm trying to detect where a mysterious System.gc() comes from,
so I'm hoping to create a pointcut on all calls to System.gc()

the doc describes how to weave existing jars and existing dirs, but
how do I weave the JDK itself ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can weave `rt.jar` beforehand and replace it in your JDK/JRE. Note that load time weaving will not work as the Javaagent does not have access to bootstrap classloader.

However, quick search reveals that there is only one place in the whole JDK (Sun 1.6.0_26) that calls `System.gc()` explicitly:

```
java.nio.Bits#reserveMemory
```

Maybe you can simply attach a debugger and put a breakpoint on `gc()` method?

That being said you can use `call()` advice as opposed to `execution()` which will weave calling client code rather than target method. So you only have to weave your code and all libraries rather than the JDK.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up compiling openJDK  after modifying the gc() source code, much easier.